# itext pdf issue

Tags: pdf, itext

I have an issue where I'm trying to open a pdf that was coded with Quark 8.51 and use itext to extract the text from the document, but when it opens there is just a long bunch of gibberish symbols and nonsensical words.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: The file can be downloaded from http://96-38-234-101.static.gwnt.ga.charter.com/Coates.pdf

Comment: Can you post the code you used to extract the text?

Answer (score 0):

Have you asked on the IText mailing list or tried any other extraction libraries like jpedal or PdfBox?

Answer (score 0):

if are trying to read anything other then just plain text it will not work. Something else that could be causing the problem is encoding